# How to make a window modal to Page in WPF?

Tags: wpf, windows, modal-dialog

I know how to make a Window Modal to a Window

I have a Page as my main window. I want to open a window and make it Modal to the Page. Is it possible? Does Page class have API's to support my requirement? If yes a sample illustration will be nice!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very simple (unless I've misunderstood your issue)

```
Window win = new MainWindow();
win.ShowDialog();
```